# Disable Auto Generation of .vscode Folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often like to use VSCode to quick view some projects to pull snippets from them. However, this leads to a ton of additional .vscode folders being placed on my drive in any folder I use the right-click -> Open with VSCode option.

Is there a way to disable this folder from being created every time vscode loads somewhere new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was due to the 'C/C++ for Visual Studio Code' extension being outdated. 
Upgrading to the latest version of this extension has fixed the problem.

Comment: The issue has come back with January 2017 update :(
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: The update fixed it for me.  No vscode folder unless I intentionally generate files that are needed for it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. it was too annoying in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the standard behaviour of VSCode, normally the `.vscode` only gets generated once there is something like a `launch.json` put into it. Mind checking what's actually in there?

Comment: It happens no matter what folder I use it on and no matter the content of the folder. For example, if I have a new folder on my desktop, I can create 3 more new folders with nothing in it. If I use VSCode to open the root folder via the 'Open With Code' context menu in Windows Explorer, it will create a .vscode folder in that root 'new folder'.

Comment: Not what's in the folder you are opening, but in the `.vscode` folder.

Comment: .BROWSE.VC.DB and .BRWOSE.VC.DB-wal files are all that get generated in this type of situation. - This appears to be caused by the C/C++ language support extension. Updated it to latest and the issue seems to be gone now.