Visual Studio workspace settings (settings.json)
I am a beginner to python programming.
I tried creating my workspace and then made some changes to my workspace settings. I was expecting to see a .vscode folder being created, with a settings.json file in it, but when I clicked on the explorer icon my vs code interface I saw nothing of that sort. But any time I make changes to my python folder which contains my python scripts, the .vscode folder and the settings.json file are created automatically.
What explains this behaviour, and how can I troubleshoot it?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40377654/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74036561/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67860202/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39815525/11107541

VSCode will not automatically create a .vscode folder when we just create a workspace without doing anything.
However, we don't need to create .vscode folder usually. When we adjust the workspace settings, vscode automatically creates the settings.json  within .vscode folder for the users.
You could use vscode command Preferences: Open Workspace Settings(JSON) or Preferences: Open Workspace Settings to open your VSCode workspace settings.

When you change the settings, vscode will automatically create the .vscode folder.


I tried doing that several times, but still no results
